# Unable to fetch data at the time of server side rendering from an API when login token is valid in Isomorphic Redux Application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-router, es6-promise

I am having a redux application with server side rendering capabilities.

Whenever user token is valid I have to regenerate the store.
When user logs in he gets **userDetails**. I set this to state of redux store after login success action is dispatched. But this same data is lost when I refresh the page and therefore to fill up this data again, I need to call other API with session token so that it can be refilled. I am unable to call that API at the time of server rendering.

I am posting code snippets here.

***action/users.js***

```
export function getUserData(){
  return {
    type: types.GET_USER_DATA,
    promise: makeUserDetailRequest('get')
  };
}

function makeUserDetailRequest(method = 'GET',data = null, api = '/user/detail') {
  return request[method](api, data);
}
```

***components/UserProfile.jsx***

class UserProfile extends Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

static need = [
    getUserData
];
render() {
 return (
  <UserProfileForm {...this.props}/>
 )
}
}

UserProfile .propTypes = {
    sessionData : PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        sessionData: state.user.sessionData
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(UserProfile );
```

***components/UserProfile.jsx***

class UserProfileForm extends Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render(){
        const { sessionData } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className={cx('jSInfoForm')}>
                <Grid>
                    <Row>
                        <Col lg={12} md={12} sm={12} xs={12}>
                            <h4 className={cx('heading')}>Primary Information</h4>
                        </Col>
                        <Col lg={12} md={12} sm={12} xs={12}>
                            <Row>
                                <Col lg={3} md={3} sm={5} xs={10}>
                                    <TextField
                                        fullWidth={true}
                                        value={this.props.sessionData.basicUserDetails[0].firstName}
                                        hintText="Enter your first name"
                                        floatingLabelText="First Name"
                                        floatingLabelFixed={true}/>
                                </Col>

                                <Col lg={3} md={3} sm={5} xs={10}>
                                    <TextField
                                        value={this.props.sessionData.basicUserDetails[0].lastName}
                                        fullWidth={true}
                                        hintText="Enter your last name"
                                        floatingLabelText="Last Name"
                                        floatingLabelFixed={true}/>
                                </Col>

                                <Col lg={6} md={6} sm={2} xs={0}/>

                                <Col lg={6} md={6} sm={6} xs={10}>
                                    <TextField
                                        fullWidth={true}
                                        value={this.props.sessionData.basicUserDetails[0].email}
                                        hintText="Enter your email"
                                        floatingLabelText="Email"
                                        floatingLabelFixed={true}/>
                                </Col>
                                <Col lg={6} md={6} sm={6} xs={2}/>

                                <Col lg={1} md={1} sm={2} xs={2}>
                                    <SelectField
                                        fullWidth={true}
                                        value={this.props.sessionData.basicUserDetails[0].isdMobile}
                                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                                        floatingLabelText="ISD"
                                        floatingLabelFixed={true}
                                        hintText="Choose ISD"
                                    >
                                        {countryIsdListItems}
                                    </SelectField>
                                </Col>
                                <Col lg={5} md={5} sm={5} xs={8}>
                                    <TextField
                                        value={this.props.sessionData.basicUserDetails[0].mobile}
                                        fullWidth={true}
                                        hintText="Enter your mobile"
                                        floatingLabelText="Mobile"
                                        floatingLabelFixed={true}/>
                                </Col>

                            </Row>

                            <Row>
                                <Col lg={5} md={5} sm={5} xs={8}>
                                    <br/>
                                    <FlatButton
                                        label="Save"
                                        labelPosition="after"
                                        primary={true}
                                        icon={<ActionSave />}
                                        style={styles.button}
                                    />
                                    <br/>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>

                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Grid>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default UserProfileForm ;
```

***preRenderMiddleware.js***

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');


export default function preRenderMiddleware(dispatch, components, params) {
  return Promise.all(
    components.reduce((previous, current) => {
      return (current.need || []).concat(previous);
    }, []).map(need => dispatch(need(params)))
  );
}
```

Comment: how do you store your token?

Comment: saving it in browser cookie

Comment: So are you unable to call the API or the API doesn't respond with valid data because you're not sending the token when making the request. In your component you can check if data exists, if yes then display the data otherwise show some loading message and make the call to the API.

Comment: I actually don't know why this static fetch is not called on server to refill my store whenever I refresh the page (server rendering)